# Calculator does not work with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have searched the internet, the library, and a dozen others that cannot supply the answer. Here is my .js file

```
// JavaScript Document
function calculate()
{
var form = document.getElementById("calc");

var text1 = document.getElementById("calculator9").value-0;
var text2 = document.getElementById("calculator13").value-0;
var x = parseFloat(text1.value);
var y = parseFloat(text2.value);  
var out = document.getElementById("calculator21").value = "$" + ((x * y) * 0.0016) - ((x * y) * 0.00085);
}
```

And here is my form on the calculator page

```
<form id="calc" name="calc" method="post" action=""> 
<div id="calculator8"> </div>
<div id="calculator9"><input type="text" name="x" class="box1" /> </div>
<div id="calculator10"> </div>
<div id="calculator11"> </div>
<div id="calculator12"> </div>
<div id="calculator13"><input type="text" name="y"  class="box2" /> </div>
<div id="calculator14"> </div>
<div id="calculator15"> </div>
<div id="calculator16"> </div>
<div id="calculator17"><input type="submit" name="submit"  class="button"   value="" onclick="calculate()" /></div>
<div id="calculator18"> </div>
<div id="calculator19"> </div>
<div id="calculator20"> </div>
<div id="calculator21"><input type="text" name="text3"  class="box3" readonly="readonly" value="" />   </div>
<div id="calculator22"> </div>
</form>
```

Can anyone help me here....this is really driving me crazy!

Comment: What does not work? What is your error?

Comment: Do you actually want the form to submit? Don't use a `type="submit"` button...use a `type="button"` button

Answer (score 1):

You are giving wrong id in your script for input fields

```
var text1 = document.getElementById("calculator9").value;
```

calculator9 is a div not a input. so try this

```
<div id="calculator13"><input type="text" id="txt9" name="y"  class="box2" /> </div>
```

and use it like this

```
var text1 = document.getElementById("txt9").value;
```

There are other problems as well in your script like

```
var x = parseFloat(text1.value);
```

here `text1.value` is undefined, use only `text1`

You can get working example here

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Tc5QU/1/)

Comment: Thank you so much...that did the trick!! I am relatively new to javascript and the syntax is a little tricky. Again, thank you for your help!!

Comment: Great. So if this solution has helped you, you can accept it as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not cancelling the click action of the submit button so the form is submitting.

```
<form id="calc" name="calc" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return false">
```

Other issues

```
var text1 = document.getElementById("calculator9").value-0;  <What is with the -0
var text2 = document.getElementById("calculator13").value-0;  <9 and 13 table cells, not inputs, they have no value!
var x = parseFloat(text1.value);  <-- text1 should be a string, not a dom object
var y = parseFloat(text2.value);
```

It should look like

```
var text1 = document.getElementById("textbox1_id").value;
var text2 = document.getElementById("textbox2_id").value;
var x = parseFloat(text1);
var y = parseFloat(text2);  
.../
var out = document.getElementById("textbox3_id").value
```

and the HTML

```
<input type="text" name="x" class="box1" id="textbox1_id"/>
<input type="text" name="y" class="box2" id="textbox2_id"/>
<input type="text" name="text3"  class="box3" readonly="readonly" value="" id="textbox3_id"/>
```

Comment: The calculator page loads and keeps the numbers in the two textboxes but does not display the answer in the third textbox. I have made the code change to reflect what @epascarello wrote but it still does the same thing....text in the two textboxes but no answer in the third textbox.

Comment: And did you look at the console for the error? You have a few issues. Editede my answer to add more.

Comment: Well, the page actually stays on the web this time but still does not display the answer in the third text and the button doesn't seem "clickable"...I am really in the dark on this one....@epascarello...what you did gave me the page staying on at least but the button does not click and initiate the function...got any other ideas....the site is [link](http://greeenhome.webatu.com) and you can see for yourself.

Comment: The calculator is working now but now I am faced with a new question of how I can display a dollar sign and monthly after the number....anyone have a guess as how to do this....I have tried several methods and so far none have worked without giving me the NaN or Not a Number in my textbox3_id

Comment: `= "$" + answer + " monthly";`